# Are there any handshake restrictions for Hindus?

Tags: scripture, culture, tradition, smriti

According to [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/46611/how-does-one-politely-decline-a-handshake-due-to-religious-reasons) on Workplace.SE:

> Muslims have some restrictions when it comes to interacting with members of the opposite sex. Usually many people in USA and Europe do not know that, for example, a Muslim man cannot shake hands with a woman. I must not touch members of the other sex at all except my spouse and siblings. This is in fact a law for me.

Are there similar restrictions for Hindu men and women?

Comment: idk about hindus in general, but for brahmins there are lot of restrictions on whom to touch, and even speak with or just see.. upon which they have to bathe to get eligibility for other vedic karmas. for any unexpected uncleanliness, they are expected to bathe thrice a day before the pratha/madhyanika/sayam sandhya. e.g., if someone just ate, but you touch them before they washed their feet, then you become ashoucha. see manu smriti for reference, can't find exact page cos so many details. men & parastri (married women) touching is definitely prohibited if you want to protect pati-vratyam.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What types of \[non-intimate\] friendly touches are allowed with other women?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27694/what-types-of-non-intimate-friendly-touches-are-allowed-with-other-women)